# stopping a soundchannel through a movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3

my question is as follows. I have a sound triggered by clicking on a movieclip, like this:

```
    var audioPlayer: SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
    var SndJuichen : Sound = new Juichen();

bootje.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, bootjeClick);
function bootjeClick (e:MouseEvent):void{

    audioPlayer = SndJuichen.play();

    }
}
```

and i want to stop this by clicking on another movieclip. for the time being, i have not been able to do this.

so I tried it by clicking on a button. like this:

```
stop_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, audioStop);
function audioStop (e:MouseEvent):void{

    addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mousedown);
    function mousedown (e:MouseEvent){
    audioPlayer.stop();
    }
}
```

At first this worked but, but when i tried it later without changing the code it didn't work anymore.

so my question is how do i get the soundchannel to stop?
I have searched for hours already, if you think you have a link that can easily fix my problem its okay too.

sincerely

Answer (score 0):

Drop the very first line `var audioPlayer: SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();` and make sure this code is run in the context of some persistent MovieClip, this way `audioPlayer` will turn into a property of that MovieClip and be accessible from another frame where you decide to stop the sound.